# Unable to containerize a NestJS microservice

Tags: docker, environment-variables, twilio, microservices, nestjs

I am trying to containerize a NestJS micro service. When I run the service directly it runs as expected. But when I build an image and then run it, I get this error:

```
9:09:10 AM - Starting compilation in watch mode...

9:09:17 AM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
/var/www/notification-service/node_modules/twilio/lib/rest/Twilio.js:139
    throw new Error('username is required');
    ^
Error: username is required
    at new Twilio (/var/www/notification-service/node_modules/twilio/lib/rest/Twilio.js:139:11)
    at Object.initializer [as default] (/var/www/notification-service/node_modules/twilio/lib/index.js:10:10)
    at Object.createTwilioClient (/var/www/notification-service/node_modules/nestjs-twilio/dist/common/twilio.utils.js:25:34)
    at Object.createTwilioProviders (/var/www/notification-service/node_modules/nestjs-twilio/dist/providers/twilio.provider.js:8:28)
    at Function.forRoot (/var/www/notification-service/node_modules/nestjs-twilio/dist/twilio-core.module.js:25:38)
    at Function.forRoot (/var/www/notification-service/node_modules/nestjs-twilio/dist/twilio.module.js:17:61)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/notification-service/dist/app.module.js:40:42)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:32)
```

When I run it without containerizing it. It seems to start fine:

```
2:40:20 pm - Starting compilation in watch mode...

2:40:24 pm - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:25 pm   [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:25 pm   [InstanceLoader] MailerModule dependencies initialized +78ms

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:25 pm   [InstanceLoader] TwilioModule dependencies initialized +1ms

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:25 pm   [InstanceLoader] TwilioCoreModule dependencies initialized +0ms

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:25 pm   [InstanceLoader] MailerCoreModule dependencies initialized +0ms

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:25 pm   [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:25 pm   [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:25 pm   [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms

Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:26 pm   [InstanceLoader] DatabaseModule dependencies initialized +123ms

[Nest] 15992   - 25/10/2021, 2:40:26 pm   [NestMicroservice] Nest microservice successfully started +5ms
```

Comment: It's almost impossible to debug something given only its error messages.  Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: are you setting any environment variables or have a config file for twilio?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The error you are getting is because you aren't providing the Twilio library with a username (Account SID or API Key). Twilio normally recommends you set your account credentials in environment variables so that they aren't part of the source code. I'm not experienced with containerizing applications, but my guess here is that when you build and run the container it no longer runs with the same environment variables available.

So, you need to find a way to get the account credentials securely into your  container so that your application can read them. I don't know much about your application from the error/running logs that you've provided, but hopefully that sets you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks @philnash. The issue came up because I was not calling the env variables with the keys inside the container.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!